# split char* into two char* by a char at the first position of the char

Tags: c

I have a char*:

```
char* version = "10.5.108";
```

I want to get two new char* by a char delimiter.

```
char delimiter = '.';
```

After executing your code following line:

```
printf("|%s|%s|", first, second);
```

should result in:

```
|10|5.108|
```

Comment: Please clarify what language you are using. C doesn't have `cout`

Comment: Have a look at `strchr()`.

Comment: Have a look at [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) too...It split string into tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch!:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>


int main(void) 
{
    char *version = "10.5.108";
    char *first, *second;

    if ( ( second = strchr( version, '.' ) ) == NULL )
    {
        first = malloc( strlen( version ) + 1 );
        strcpy( first, version );
        second = malloc( sizeof( char ) );
        *second = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        ptrdiff_t n = second - version;
        first = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
        second = malloc ( ( strlen( version ) - n ) * sizeof( char ) );

        strncpy( first, version, n );
        first[n] = '\0';
        strcpy( second, version + n + 1 );
    }

    printf( "|%s|%s|", first, second );

    free( first );
    free( second );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
|10|5.108|
```